# How to capitalize the "Login" Address in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to capitalize the first letter ofv"Login" Address.

localhost:8000/login to localhost:8000/Login ...

How can I do that?

Comment: Make the change in the routing [basic route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#basic-routing)

Comment: @Alaeddine Can you show me a example ? Thanks

Comment: @Ali - Change the case in your routing... It's really that simple.

Comment: @MikeRockett Thanks Mike for your response, but I'm a beginner & I don't know how to change that codes ...

Comment: `Route::get('Login', function() {...});` - Just use the capital letter in your routing.

Comment: @MikeRockett Thank you very much Mike ...